# Select like Query for array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i am having a this functions in my PHP code

```
function a() {
//Q1 = query database and gets 13k records
//now call function b and c and pass some arguments along (which are result of Q1)
foreach(Q1){
 b();   
 c();
 }   
}//end of function a    

function b(){   
//Q2 = query database TB1 and search against 30k rows to get 1 row 
return $result;      
}

function c(){   
//Q2 = query database TB2 and search against 30k rows to get 1 row 
return $result;      
}
```

Now when i run this code it makes many calls to DB as each function b and c are called for every 13k records in loop which makes my whole application other mysql connections on halt.

So i was thinking to store the records of my  TB1 and TB2 in some array and query that array for fetching data rather than mysql.after googling i found **PHPLinq** can be used for this..but is this **right way to do using PHPLinq** or should i use some **other way to store data in array and query that array for records**.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use JOINS in your query to limit the amount of queries?

Comment: no..scenario cannot be changed..i just want some way where i can avoid sql calls.

Comment: In the function a use if( (empty(array1) && (empty(array2)){ $array1 = b();$array2 = c();} else { do what you want }

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced that using PHPLinq would be wise here. You may perform only one call but storing all this will be costly for the first fetch from the database, then storing a lot of items in the memory and finally iterating over it will be a real pain (and might force your script to crash).

Two improvements I see fit are:

A/ Use PDO classes and use the "prepare" method when possible (take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php))

B/ Try to "merge" you SQL queries when possible. Is it not possible for you to perform B and C in the same SQL query ? Or even better, the 3 parts in the same query.

C/ Another solution would be to create temporary SQL tables and populate it with values used in subqueries (the one you perform in functions B and C). You'd let your SQL database handle all the heavy-duty work and just query it as if it was a CSV file, aside from saving some RAM on your client.

D/ As suggested by @despina, a view could also prove useful to expose more possibly useful information in one request.

Comment: no dude..i also have some calculations in functions which requires me to call each of this functions individually..

Comment: i want something where i can store data in array or something else rather than mysql tables.

Comment: Another solution would be to create temporary SQL tables and populate it with values used in subqueries (the one you perform in functions B and C). You'd let your SQL database handle all the heavy-duty work and just query it as if it was a CSV file, aside from saving some RAM on your client.